# IE navigation dropdown doesn't display as it should

Tags: html, css

I've created a drop down navigation in html. I then tested it with different browser such as chrome, firefox, opera and IE. The only problem I see is that the navigation doesn't display right in IE.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_bar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html" title="Go to our Home Page.">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Krazie</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="krazie/colour.html" title="Go to Krazie's Colour portfolio.">Colour</a></li>
                <br />
                <li><a href="krazie/black.html" title="Go to Krazie's Black 'N' Grey portfolio.">Black 'N' Grey</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
<!-- End of Krazie links -->            
        <li><a href="#">Stacy</a>
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="stacy/colour.html" title="Go to Stacy's Colour portfolio.">Colour</a></li>
                <br />
                <li><a href="stacy/black.html" title="Go to Stacy's Black 'N' Grey portfolio.">Black 'N' Grey</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
<!-- End of stacy links -->         
        <li><a href="#">Matt</a>
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="matt/colour.html" title="Go to Matt's Colour portfolio.">Colour</a></li>
                <br />
                <li><a href="matt/black.html" title="Go to Matt's Black 'N' Grey portfolio.">Black 'N' Grey</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
<!-- End of matt links -->          
        <li><a href="contact.html" title="Go to our Contact page.">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav 
{
    margin-top:-0px;
    background:rgb(108,108,108);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9003;
    height:32px;
    list-style:none;
    color:#FFF;
}

#nav li 
{ 
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav li a 
{
    display: block;
    height:2em;
    line-height:2em;
    padding:0px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    color:#FFF;
}

#nav ul 
{   
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    background:rgb(108,108,108);
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index:9003;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li a
{
    padding:-50px;
    width:110px;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
}   

#nav > li:hover > a 
{
    background:rgb(108,108,108);
}

#nav ul li:hover  a
{    
    background:rgb(48,48,50);
}
```

The bit that doesn't display properly is the actual links that you see when you put the mouse over them. This is how it shows on other browser like chrome: http://grab.by/e5ik
but in IE it displays as: http://grab.by/e5im

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes seems too complicated to get your work done.

Btw, please remove `<br />` in html.

Then, add the following CSS: (between `#nav ul` and `#nav ul li a`)

```
#nav ul li {
    clear: both;
}
```

(tested in IE8)

Please check again in the browsers whether any error occurs.

Comment: Yeah, but to be honest, it seemed the easiest (sorta) way to do it. And I had the <br /> tags in there because I didn't want the links to display as one line, so I thought that would of done it. :) And could you explain or re-direct me to a site that could explain the 'clear' css to me please. Thanks

Comment: I read a book called "Professional XHTML & CSS: Creative and Practice of Web Designer" a few years ago. Its author is Japanese and I read the Chinese version. It explained a lot of best practice in design (e.g. when to use br/, how display:block affect the blind readers). It's worth to read. I hope they publish an English version too.

Answer (score 0):

change this-

```
#nav ul li a
{
    padding:-50px;
    width:110px;
    list-style:none;
}    
#nav li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
}   

#nav > li:hover > a 
{
    background:rgb(108,108,108);
}

#nav ul li:hover a
{    
    background:rgb(48,48,50);
}
```

to this-

```
#nav ul li a
{
    padding:-50px;
    width:110px;
    list-style:none;
    display:block
}    
#nav a:hover ul
    {
        display:block;
        list-style:none;
    }   

    #nav > li > a:hover
    {
        background:rgb(108,108,108);
    }

    #nav ul li a:hover
    {    
        background:rgb(48,48,50);
    }
```

sometimes ie doesn't recognize hovering over elements except `a` elements.

Comment: Hmm I entered it now it has stopped the drop down from showing at all. For the IE hover, does this occur for all IE or just late ones?